# python setup.py egg_info mysqlclient

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, mysql-python, macos-sierra

Trying to install mysqlclient using pip3 on Python 3.6.0

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in <listcomp>
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3k/08g3yx_12kg99kyfs989md600000gn/T/pip-build-1qv_89jc/mysqlclient/
```

Already did

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

But still getting this error

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This worked for me:

1. `brew install mysql-connector-c`
2. edit `mysql_config` (locate it: `which mysql_config`)

correct this in mysql_config:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l "
```

It shoud be:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

4. `brew info openssl`
5. and finally `pip3 install mysqlclient`

Comment: Works like a charm!! The Best solution, I think!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: You should change permissions or edit it with Vim and use _wq!_ for saving changes

Comment: Awesome!! Worked for me too. Thanks so much. :D

Comment: Do you have open ssl library? Try brew install openssl

Comment: for python 2.7 you don't need cypto. SSL will do the client.
Also, add to set this the installation to read ssl:
 export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" (you can find this info by running `brew info openssl` as mentioned).

Comment: For my comprehension, what does the 4. point (`brew info openssl`) is it necessary ?

Answer (score 24):

I resolved this installing libmysqlclient-dev first:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: The OP mentions "OSX"

Comment: @FranklinAntony Sorry, it fixed to me the same error on Linux, but for Mac it would be: brew install mysql see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857861/libmysqlclient15-dev-on-macs

Comment: Thanks. Your answer fixs the issue I met on Ubuntu 22.04 too.

Answer (score 6):

After *extensive* troubleshooting, I found that the `brew install mysql-connector-c` just does not work.

The problem stems from the system not being able to identify that `mysql_config` is installed (which is what `mysql-connector-c` essentially does). Homebrew's method (open for argument) of installing the `mysql-connector-c` in its `/Cellar/` and creating a symlink to the `/usr/local/bin/` directory seems to be causing problems as Python tries to follow the symlink.

To resolve the issue I performed the following:

1. `brew uninstall mysql-connector-c`
2. download/install [MacOS X MySQL Connector/C](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/) from Oracle's MySQL site

   - note: just download the `.dmg`, no need to be complicated here...
3. restart MacOS Terminal (or iTerm2) for good measure
4. `which mysql_config`

   - you should see the correct path `/usr/local/bin/mysql/bin/mysql_config`
5. activate `virtualenv` (if applicable)
6. `pip install mysqlclient`

There may be other ways to still use Homebrew, but this was the most straightforward solution I found.

Note that the `mysqlclient` GitHub README.md also states that the C-developer headers for Python3 are needed. I assume that `mysql-connector-c` includes those; however, should you run into more issues, you might also install the Xcode Developer CI Tools for good measure.

`xcode-select --install`

They include the C compiler and other developer utilities from Apple. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/devguide/setup.html#build-dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

Came across this while developing a django-based website, and I needed to set up the website to communicate with a mysql database. I've not used homebrew to do any of my installations.

Since I'm doing the development on a MacOS with Anaconda installed, I discovered that there was an issue with Anaconda. Without knowing the details, I was able to install mysqlclient with `conda install mysqlclient`

Hope that helps someone else with this problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2.7 on specific programs:

1. sudo chown -R $USER /Library/Python/2.7
2. brew install mysql@5.7
3. brew install mysql-connector-c
4. brew link --overwrite mysql@5.7
5. echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
6. sed -i -e 's/libs="$libs -l "/libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"/g' /usr/local/bin/mysql_config
7. pip install MySql-python

This solved all issues I was having running a program that ran on Python 2.7 on and older version of MySql

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on MacOS 10+.
Rather than directly installing mysqlclient using pip, use this command first

```
brew install mysql
```

If you do not have an existing setup for brew, then install brew from it's homepage

Then run

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

This should work! Also ensure you have a virtualenv set up for your projects, as it is among good practices to maintain venv's for each project seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Other options didn't work for me, but this worked for me:

For Python3:

`env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip3 install mysqlclient`

For Python2:

`env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip2 install mysqlclient`

or

`env LDFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 0):

Personally I recommend using `pymysql` instead of using `mysqlclient`. You can install `pymysql` with:

`pip install pymysql`

And you might edit your SQLAlchemy URL to:

`mysql+pymysql://username:passwd@hostname/database`

Answer (score 0):

I'm just getting started with python and had similar problems when trying to do `pip3 install mysqlclient` to connect Django to MySQL 8.0.19 but on my case it is on a macOS Catalina 10.15.5 with Python 3.8. I also tried `brew install mysql-connector-c` but it also gave me a lot of trouble. Here's how I manage to make it work.

1. `brew reinstall mysql`
2. `brew install mysql-client`

- Note: After installing `mysql-client` I got the following messages in the terminal which I just followed and got all to work.
- mysql-client is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local, because it conflicts with mysql (which contains client libraries). If you need to have mysql-client first in your PATH run:

3. `echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

- For compilers to find mysql-client you may need to set:

4. `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib"`
5. `export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/include"`

- Then I just tried to install mysqlclient again and it worked. I also tried it on a python .venv environment and it worked as well using:

6. `pip3 install mysqlclient`

References: [Install mysqlclient for Django Python on Mac OS X Sierra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634119/3802757)

Hope this works as it did for me today.
Regards,
Alfredo

Answer (score 0):

For those who have similar error while trying to build `python:<version>-alpine` docker image, here is the solution:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine

<...>

RUN apk update \
    && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
    && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev

RUN python -m pip install mysqlclient==2.1.1
```

### Details

If fact, it is similar to [@yosbel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44141634/7744106). But his answer is for debian-like linux systems (e.g. Ubuntu).

Error message I got with alpine image is below:

```
Collecting mysqlclient==2.1.1
Downloading mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 88.1/88.1 kB 6.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.

<...>

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```