# Cannot pip3 install mysqlclient

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pip, mysql-python

pip3 install mysqlclient

shows the following error,

```
    Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/58/m4f65nln59dbf0sf6x70l5zw0000gn/T/pip-build-ruton_ve/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/private/var/folders/58/m4f65nln59dbf0sf6x70l5zw0000gn/T/pip-build-ruton_ve/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in get_config
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/58/m4f65nln59dbf0sf6x70l5zw0000gn/T/pip-build-ruton_ve/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 54, in <listcomp>
        libraries = [dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith('-l')]
      File "/private/var/folders/58/m4f65nln59dbf0sf6x70l5zw0000gn/T/pip-build-ruton_ve/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 12, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/58/m4f65nln59dbf0sf6x70l5zw0000gn/T/pip-build-ruton_ve/mysqlclient/
```

followed some posts and installed

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

But Still facing the issue.

For other solution tried the following solution,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44338332/4107739

but couldn't find /usr/local/bin/mysql/bin/mysql_config

I'm running on MacOS, for Mysql I have XAMPP installed.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools`

Answer (score 4):

For python3 + mysql on mac. This worked for me:

1. `brew install mysql-connector-c`
2. edit mysql_config (locate it: `which mysql_config`)

Change the following in mysql_config:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -l "
```

To:

```
# Create options 
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

3. `brew info openssl`
4. and finally `pip3 install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 1):

in XAMPP, the mysql_config would be somewhere in the below path. (based where you installed)

```
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql_config
```

Update the $PATH to include bin path

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/
```

Run mysql_config, `--libs` and `--libs_r` should have `-lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto`,

```
 <XAMPP_PATH>mysql_config | grep libs
        --libs           [-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto]
        --libs_r         [-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto]
        --libmysqld-libs [-L/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.21/lib -lmysqld -lssl -lcrypto]
```

if not, update the mysql_config to following values.

```
libs="-L$pkglibdir"
libs="$libs -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto"
```

then run

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

Comment: I had the same issue and I added

`export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/`

 in ~/.bash_profile and then ran

`pip3 install mysqlclient`
 
It worked