# I can't install flask-mysqldb via pip?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, flask, pip

I'm trying to install **flask-mysqldb** via pip but i'm getting an error. Here are some details:

- Python Version: 3.7.7
- Operating System: Windows 10
- Pip Version: 20.1
- Cannot **pip install flask-mysqldb**

Here is a summary of the error i'm getting...

`ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\dogiy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\dogiy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vnpzkr37\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\dogiy\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-vnpzkr37\\mysqlclient\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\dogiy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-f31t4q22\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\dogiy\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Include\mysqlclient' Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901139/error-during-installation-of-flask-mysqldb-python-3-on-a-mac-os-high-sierra

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error during installation of flask-mysqldb (python 3) on a mac (OS High Sierra)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50901139/error-during-installation-of-flask-mysqldb-python-3-on-a-mac-os-high-sierra)

Comment: I'm using Windows 10, tried it and no it doesn't...