# Install mysqlclient via pipenv throw errors

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

I'm using django and mysql.

To communicate django with mysql, have to install mysqlclient.

Also python version is 3.7.2

`pipenv install mysqlclient`

it throws errors.

```
Installing mysqlclient...
✔ Installation Succeeded 
Pipfile.lock (c98c3a) out of date, updating to (a65489)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
✔ Success! 
Updated Pipfile.lock (c98c3a)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (c98c3a)...
An error occurred while installing mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1 --hash=sha256:425e733b05e359a714d6007c0fc44582be66b63e5a3df0a50949274ae16f4bc6 --hash=sha256:62e4770b6a797b9416bcf70488365b7d6b9c9066878108499c559293bb464380 --hash=sha256:f257d250f2675d0ef99bd318906f3cfc05cef4a2f385ea695ff32a3f04b9f9a7! Will try again.
     ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 1/1 — 00:00:02
Installing initially failed dependencies...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1992, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       skip_lock=skip_lock,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1253, in do_init
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 859, in do_install_dependencies
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       retry_list, procs, failed_deps_queue, requirements_dir, **install_kwargs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 763, in batch_install
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       _cleanup_procs(procs, not blocking, failed_deps_queue, retry=retry)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 681, in _cleanup_procs
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]:       raise exceptions.InstallError(c.dep.name, extra=err_lines)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['Collecting mysqlclient==1.4.2.post1 (from -r /var/folders/ll/4ql5wb555rqb9xcsdzr624b80000gn/T/pipenv-bV3RGM-requirements/pipenv-bOkuhH-requirement.txt (line 1))', '  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz', 'Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient', '  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py): started', "  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py): finished with status 'error'", '  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient', 'Failed to build mysqlclient', 'Installing collected packages: mysqlclient', '  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: started', "    Running setup.py install for mysqlclient: finished with status 'error'"]
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ['ERROR: Complete output from command /Users/hide/.local/share/virtualenvs/horang-mnXaGoVY/bin/python3.7 -u -c \'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=\'"\'"\'/private/var/folders/ll/4ql5wb555rqb9xcsdzr624b80000gn/T/pip-install-83zphs9u/mysqlclient/setup.py\'"\'"\';f=getattr(tokenize, \'"\'"\'open\'"\'"\', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(\'"\'"\'\\r\\n\'"\'"\', \'"\'"\'\\n\'"\'"\');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, \'"\'"\'exec\'"\'"\'))\' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/ll/4ql5wb555rqb9xcsdzr624b80000gn/T/pip-wheel-jhcy1h95 --python-tag cp37:', '  ERROR: running bdist_wheel', '  running build', '  running build_py', '  creating build', '  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7', '  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '  copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '  creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '  warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.', '  ', '  running build_ext', "  building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension", '  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7', '  creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', "  clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o", '  clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so', '  ld: library not found for -lssl', '  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)', "  error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1", '  ----------------------------------------', '  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient', '    ERROR: Complete output from command /Users/hide/.local/share/virtualenvs/horang-mnXaGoVY/bin/python3.7 -u -c \'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=\'"\'"\'/private/var/folders/ll/4ql5wb555rqb9xcsdzr624b80000gn/T/pip-install-83zphs9u/mysqlclient/setup.py\'"\'"\';f=getattr(tokenize, \'"\'"\'open\'"\'"\', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(\'"\'"\'\\r\\n\'"\'"\', \'"\'"\'\\n\'"\'"\');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, \'"\'"\'exec\'"\'"\'))\' install --record /private/var/folders/ll/4ql5wb555rqb9xcsdzr624b80000gn/T/pip-record-t6u87iq3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/hide/.local/share/virtualenvs/horang-mnXaGoVY/bin/../include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient:', '    ERROR: running install', '    running build', '    running build_py', '    creating build', '    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7', '    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '    copying MySQLdb/_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', '    creating build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/constants', '    warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.', '    ', '    running build_ext', "    building 'MySQLdb._mysql' extension", '    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7', '    creating build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb', "    clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -Dversion_info=(1,4,2,'post',1) -D__version__=1.4.2.post1 -I/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/include/mysql -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o", '    clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk build/temp.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/local/opt/mysql@5.7/lib -lmysqlclient -lssl -lcrypto -o build/lib.macosx-10.14-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so', '    ld: library not found for -lssl', '    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)', "    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1", '    ----------------------------------------', 'ERROR: Command "/Users/hide/.local/share/virtualenvs/horang-mnXaGoVY/bin/python3.7 -u -c \'import setuptools, tokenize;__file__=\'"\'"\'/private/var/folders/ll/4ql5wb555rqb9xcsdzr624b80000gn/T/pip-install-83zphs9u/mysqlclient/setup.py\'"\'"\';f=getattr(tokenize, \'"\'"\'open\'"\'"\', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace(\'"\'"\'\\r\\n\'"\'"\', \'"\'"\'\\n\'"\'"\');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, \'"\'"\'exec\'"\'"\'))\' install --record /private/var/folders/ll/4ql5wb555rqb9xcsdzr624b80000gn/T/pip-record-t6u87iq3/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/hide/.local/share/virtualenvs/horang-mnXaGoVY/bin/../include/site/python3.7/mysqlclient" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/ll/4ql5wb555rqb9xcsdzr624b80000gn/T/pip-install-83zphs9u/mysqlclient/']
ERROR: ERROR: Package installation failed...
```

I tried `pipenv install mysqlclient==1.13.13`, it doens't work too.

Is there any solution here?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed client lib? sudo apt install libmysqlclient-dev . After that is installed then try maybe?

Comment: @JoeA I'm using OSX and it is virtual environment.

Comment: Hmmmmmm I'm going to refer you to two links which might help cause I'm not 100% positive on Mac OSX https://medium.com/@shandou/pipenv-install-mysqlclient-on-macosx-7c253b0112f2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43612243/install-mysqlclient-for-django-python-on-mac-os-x-sierra

Comment: Did you find an answer? I'm running into this same issue.

Comment: @Kristen I added answer. Please check it.

Comment: Any suggestions for windows users?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**SOLVED**

```
brew install openssl
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib pip install mysqlclient
```

I'm using OSX Mojave and I think it caused by osx version.

Comment: is it a must to install by `pip` instead of `pipenv`?

Answer (score 11):

I had to install these 3 packages first to get it to work for me:

- python3-dev
- libmysqlclient-dev
- libssl-dev

Especially true if you are on a cloud server where they strip the OS down a bit.
Heres the copy paste command:

```
sudo apt install -y python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev libssl-dev
```

Fews years later update: Having gone down the road of `pipenv`, I don't recommend it, I now use `venv`

Answer (score 8):

Install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Note that you need `python3.7-dev` not `python3-dev`.

Then run:

```
pipenv install
```

Answer (score 3):

for anyone coming here using ubuntu 19.10 a quick:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

followed by

```
pipenv install mysqlclient
```

this solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

if you're on mac, just update/install your brew and then run the same command it will work

- if you get the shallow clone error
  -perform unshallow commands and then hit the brew command.

post all that, come back and run the sudo pipenv install mysqlclient

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem but none of the answers in this thread and in many many other threads worked. So, if you have tried all other steps and it is still not working for you, try the following:

Install pkg-config through apt.

```
apt install pkg-config
```

I am using Ubuntu 22.0 on WSL 2.0, Windows 10.